# should the "->" symbol not be used in a php script for database connection? if it cant be used, what is the alternative?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

The following is my code, in which I have 2 text boxes named `fyear` and `ayear`. This code is not working, as, I am unable to connect it with the MySQL database. What might be the problem and how could I overcome it? I'm using PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>



<body style="background-color:#708090;">

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $mysqli= new mysqli("localhost","admin","admin", "nba" );

    if($mysqli === false)
    {
        die("could not connect:" . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    if ($inputError != true && empty($_POST['ayear']) )
    {
        echo 'ERROR: Please enter a valid year';
        $inputError = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $ayear = $mysqli-> escape_string($_POST['ayear']);
    }

    if ($inputError != true && empty($_POST['fyear']) )
    {
        echo 'ERROR: Please enter a valid year';
        $inputError = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $fyear = $mysqli->  escape_string($_POST['fyear']);
    }   

    if ($inputError != true)
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO year VALUES ('$ayear','$fyear')";
        if ($mysqli-> query($sql)==true)
        {
            echo'Added';
        }
        else
        {
            echo"ERROR: Could not execute query : $sql. " . $mysqli-> error;
        }
    }

    $mysqli-> close();

}
?> 







<h1 style="font-family:Verdana;text-align:center;">National Board of Accrediation <br>of<br> Master of Computer Applications Programme</h1>
<br>

<div id="menu" style="background-color:#800000;height:25px;width:1000px">
<b><font "style="font-family:Verdana"><a href="part1.html" title="Institutional Summary"style="color: #000000">Part I</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<a href="part2.html"title="Departmental/Program Summary"style="color: #000000">Part II</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<a href="part3.html"title="Curricula,Syllabi,PEOs and POs"style="color: #000000">Part III</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<a href="part4.html" title="List of Documents to be made available during the visit"style="color: #000000">Part IV</a></font></b>
</div>


<form   method="post" action="home.php"> <p> This  Report  is prepared for the Current Acadamic Year(<input type="text" size="9"  name="ayear" id="ayear" onChange="a('ayear');">) and the Current Financial Year (<input type="text" size="9"  name="fyear" id="fyear" onChange="a('fyear');">) on behalf of the Institution.</p>



<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is from this part:

```
else
        {
            $ayear = $mysqli-> escape_string($_POST['ayear']);
        }
```

After the ">" symbol, everything is getting printed in the web page. What could be the possible solution for this? I've gone through this code but couldn't find out what the mistake is.

Comment: i am sure you know what `->` and how it works

Comment: Try and work away from the `die()`, this should never be used in production, let alone testing.  [Read this!](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP did not process your script at all, so that `<?php ... ->` was interpreted as a HTML tag. Look at the HTML source code in your browser.

Is the script saved as `.php`? Is PHP installed on your server?

Comment: I guess not because of `<form method="post" action="home.html">`

Comment: yes sir it is saved in .php extention. still it isn't working

Comment: create a new php file and add <?php phpinfo() ?> to it, then see if it shows a blue table or just the text '<?php phpinfo() ?>'

Comment: i had changed from .php to .html but result was the same and again changed to .php. it isn't working you can try and run the code.

Comment: Try placing on top: `ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: Then PHP is not installed on your server or connected to your webserver (i.e. if apache: `mod_php` active) or it is not configured to handle `.php` files (unlikely). All assuming that you copied the script to a web server and visited the URL in your browser. Viewing it from your local filesystem does not work because PHP runs on the server, not in your browser.