# echo "<p>" . $value . "</p>";

Tags: php, html

Ok my first time asking question here. This as been very helpful in the past but now i'm lost.
I'm trying to understand how php work with the help of a book. So i did the exercise as it was shown in the book and the result if not what it should be.

Here's the code:

```
<div id="content">
    <p>Here's a record of everything in the REQUEST array:</p>
    <?php
    foreach($_REQUEST as $value) {
        echo "<p>" . $value . "</p>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

And here's the result:

> Here's a record of everything in the REQUEST array:
>
> ```
> " . $value . "
> "; } ?>
> ```

Why is not showing the info it is suppose to? Thanks.

---

Ok here's all the code:

showRequestInfo.php

> 

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
> "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html
> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta
> http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <link
> href="/wamp/www/livrephp/css/phpMM.css" type="text/css"
> rel="stylesheet" />
> 
> <title>Untitled Document</title> </head>
> 
> <body>    <div id="header"><h1>PHP & MySQL: The Missing
> manual</h1></div>
>     <div id="example">Example 3-2</div>
>     
>     <div id="content">
>       <p>Here's a record of everything in the REQUEST array:</p>
>         <?php         foreach($_REQUEST as $value) {          echo "<p>" . $value . "</p>";           }           ?>
>             
>           
>         </div>
>         <div id="footer"></div> </body> </html>
```

And this goes with this file called "socialEntryForm.php"

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="/wamp/www/livrephp/css/phpMM.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header"><h1>PHP & MySQL: The misiing manual</h1></div>
    <div id="example">Example -1</div>

    <div id="content">
        <h1>Join the missing manual (Digital) Social Club</h1>
        <p>Please enter your online connections below:</p>
        <form action="../showRequestInfo.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" size="20" /><br />
            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" size="20" /><br />
            <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" size="50" /><br />
            <label for="facebook_url">Facebook URL:</label>
            <input type="text" name="facebook_url" size="50" /><br />
            <label for="twitter_handle">Twitter Handle:</label>
            <input type="text" name="twitter_handle" size="50" /><br />
            </fieldset>
            <br />
            <fieldset class="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Join The Club" />
                <input type="reset" value="Clear and Restart" />
            </fieldset>
          </form>
     </div>

     <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the quotes correct? The code you showed should work.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running this in a PHP-enabled environment, e.g. on a webserver?

Comment: Is the code above your code, all your code, exactly your code, and nothing but your code?

Comment: Try just [`phpinfo();`](http://php.net/phpinfo)

Comment: definitely looks like mismatched quotes given your output, but the code snippet looks good

Comment: `code`<html>
<head>
<link href="/wamp/www/livrephp/css/phpMM.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="header"><h1>PHP & MySQL: The Missing manual</h1></div>
    <div id="example">Example 3-2</div>
    
    <div id="content">
     <p>Here's a record of everything in the REQUEST array:</p>
        <?php
  foreach($_REQUEST as $value) {
   echo "<p>" . $value . "</p>";
   }
   ?>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>`code`

Comment: basically the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578842/should-the-symbol-not-be-used-in-a-php-script-for-database-connection-if-i/14578904#14578904

Comment: Remove the quotes, and type them again manually.

Comment: Guys.. The code he has posted in his question is correct.. He's lacking a html form. see my answer

Comment: here's the book and the original code http://blog.csdn.net/xiaocaiju/article/details/7850372

Comment: @MatthieuOuellette Can you open your browser, view the source, and include that in your question? Also tell us the URL in your address bar when running the script.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you write the code in something like word? Not that I'm suggesting this is the problem, but word processors can add extra info that can affect how the file is read. Copy and paste here may not translate the hidden characters or relay the encoding of the original file. Try wiping the file directly on the server and editing there via vim or an ftp interface

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure your file is a PHP file and it's being run on a PHP enabled server? The browser seems to be receiving the code unparsed, thinking that there's a tag starting at `<?php` and ending at the first `<p>` tag. If you look at the source, you'll probably see your PHP code, untouched by the server.

In other words: Your code is correct and the problem is your file type or server configuration. If you *are indeed* using a server on your machine, make sure you're running the file right, e.g. if it's in the root, open `http://localhost/your_file.php`, and not `C:\xampp\htdocs\your_file.php`.

**EDIT:** Just for the heck of it, I replicated your issue with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9j8c8/). I got the exact same output as you, meaning it's not getting parsed by the server. Who said JSFiddle was only good for JavaScript?

Comment: heh... i ran this on my server as php but didn't bother running it as html. plus 1 to you

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST` Contains data which is gathered from cookies, `$_POST` and `$_GET` .. Are you sure that your data is properly assigned?

Take this example.

`print_r($_REQUEST);`  just doing that without no `<form method="get/post">` will produce a blank array, that might be why you are getting nothing

Your snippet is correct.. you are lacking a html form to go with that..

Example:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="test" value="ThisIsCorrect">
</form>
```

With your code you have shown your question.. your `$_REQUEST` array will return the value of the button. In this case "ThisIsCorrect"

---

Moral Of this?

Ensure that you are using using post/get/cookies before calling the $_REQUEST, and for future reference, just using $_POST & $_GET is cleaner to use.. But that is down to my personal preference.

---

How is the $_REQUEST Array constructed?

Consider this:

the array will contain the `name` as the array key and the value as the value..

So taking this into account:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="submit" name="test" value="ThisIsCorrect">
</form>
```

For your text box & Submit button the array will be:

`array ("username" => "UserInputData",
  "test" => "ThisIsCorrect");`

Comment: That's not the reason why it is behaving this way. foreach will just do nothing if the array is empty. His is doing something and something odd. You can run this on a test server to verify. I just did and it did not error... probably because I'm actually running it as php

Comment: PHP code is never dependent of HTML to be able to run. His output does not reflect an unset variable like you're suggesting. If it were an unset variable, he'd be getting a notice from PHP.

Comment: I have ran it on both my local lamp server and Windows apache stack to eliminate the possibility of cross platform misconfigurations.. The code runs fine.

and @thordarson PHP isn't dependent on HTML? In some cases this is true, in others this is false.. from the HTML you can populate the `$_POST & $_GET` array from a HTML form.. Without no submission, the $_REQUEST will remain blank

Comment: I told you, in those cases he'd be getting a notice from PHP (granted, depending on his configuration of php.ini). Not a malformed output.

Comment: it's showing an uninterpreted PHP code block so it's def not an issue with not sending data through a form.

Comment: no, in all cases it is true. html is output from php, not the other way around. the warnings you may get running foreach on an empty array have to do with your php settings and error reporting. You can turn this off if desired.

Comment: @KaiQing running a foreach loop on a nonexistent variable will return an error; but there are pre-defined blank arrays which are safe to run a foreach loop; perhaps not in best practice..  But you can run a foreach on $_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE, $_REQUEST  without having data in.. will be returned with nothing

Comment: That is true. My point was the dependency thing. But in all fairness, you are likely meaning that the values of these arrays are dependent on anything that sends an http request of any kind. Javascript, inbound server calls originating from any applicable language, etc

Comment: @DarylGill See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9j8c8/). It's not getting parsed by a server and, alas, it's output is exactly the same as OP's.

Comment: Okay guys, I seriously misread the question; but my answer still stands just incase someone finds this question in the hope of having a little more information in $_request.